# Package not found error while installing CuSpatial or CuDf library

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

So, to calculate [Hausdorff Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) in a short time I found a [CuSpatial](https://medium.com/rapids-ai/releasing-cuspatial-to-accelerate-geospatial-and-spatiotemporal-processing-b686d8b32a9) library or cudf library. But while trying to install it through the [Anaconda Promt](https://anaconda.org/rapidsai-nightly/cuspatial) `conda install -c rapidsai-nightly cuspatial` i get the following:

> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
>
> - cuspatial
>
> Current channels:
>
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/rapidsai-nightly/win-64
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/rapidsai-nightly/noarch
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
>
> To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package
>   you're looking for, navigate to
>
> ```
> https://anaconda.org
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but no **win-64** builds are available for that on Anaconda Cloud. The developers only seem to support Linux 64, but I suppose if you're adventurous you can attempt [a build from source](https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf/blob/branch-0.11/CONTRIBUTING.md#setting-up-your-build-environment).